# How to get json array and insert in the database. php

Tags: php, mysql, json, associative-array

I have a table on an Invitation. I am passing the data in json format from postman.

I want to send many invitations at a time. So I want to insert multiple invitations.

How can I do this?

I have created a single invitation.

Invitaion :

```
    class Invitation
{
    private $sender_id,$date,$invitee_no,$status;

    function Invitation($sender_id,$date,$invitee_no,$status)
    {

        $this->sender_id = $sender_id;
        $this->date= $date;
        $this->invitee_no = $invitee_no;
        $this->status = $status;

    }
    function sendInvite()
    {

        $database = new Database(ContactsConstants::DBHOST,ContactsConstants::DBUSER,ContactsConstants::DBPASS,ContactsConstants::DBNAME);
        $dbConnection = $database->getDB();

        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("select * from Invitation where invitee_no =?");
        $stmt->execute(array($this->invitee_no));
        $rows = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($rows > 0)
        {
            $response = array("status"=>-3,"message"=>"Invitation exists.");
            return $response;
        }

            $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("insert into Invitation(date,invitee_no,status) values(?,?,?)");
            $stmt->execute(array($this->date, $this->invitee_no, $this->status));
            $rows = $stmt->rowCount();
            $Id = $dbConnection->lastInsertId();

            $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("select * from Invitation where sender_id=?");
            $stmt->execute(array($Id));
            $invitation = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if ($rows < 1) {
                $response = array("status" => -1, "message" => "Failed to send Invitation., unknown reason");
                return $response;
            } else {
                $response = array("status" => 1, "message" => "Invitation sent.", "Invitation:" => $invitation);
                return $response;
            }

    }
}
```

sendInvite.php

```
    <?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require 'Invitation.php';

$jsonText = file_get_contents('php://input');

if(empty($jsonText))
{
    $response = array("status"=>-2,"message"=>"Empty request");
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$json = json_decode($jsonText);

$date= $json -> date;
$invitee_no = $json -> invitee_no;
$status = $json -> status;

$invitation = new Invitation("",$date,$invitee_no,$status);
$response = $invitation->sendInvite();

echo(json_encode($response));

?>
```

Input from postman:

```
{

"date" : "12/08/2016",
"invitee_no" : "5258",
"status" : "1"
}
```

Output:

```
   {
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Invitation sent.",
  "Invitation:": [
    {
      "sender_id": "29",
      "date": "12/08/2016",
      "invitee_no": "5259",
      "status": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT:

In Send Invite() function:

```
if ($rows < 1) {

        $response = array("status" => -1, "message" => "Failed to send Invitation., unknown reason");
        echo(json_encode($response));

    } else {
        $response = array("status" => 1, "message" => "Invitation sent.", "Invitation:" => $invitation);
        echo(json_encode($response));

    }
```

In senInvite.php file :

```
    foreach ($json as $jsn) {
    foreach($jsn as $j)
    {
        $date= $j -> date;
        $invitee_no = $j -> invitee_no;
        $status = $j -> status;
        $invitation = new Invitation("",$date,$invitee_no,$status);
        $response = $invitation->sendInvite();

        var_dump($response);
        die();

        echo(json_encode($response));
    }

}
```

var dump:

```
{"status":-3,"message":"Invitation exists.","invitee_no":"5856"}array(3) {
  ["status"]=>
  int(-3)
  ["message"]=>
  string(18) "Invitation exists."
  ["invitee_no"]=>
  string(4) "5856"
}
```

Gives syntax error: unexpeted 'S'

I want to accept this as json array and insert into the table all the records.

Can anyone help please? Thank you..

Comment: How are you sending values to sendInvite.php? How are you sending input from postman to sendInvite.php?

Comment: I have added input and output to the question. @ShoyebSheikh

Comment: Bro how are you getting values in this variable ------->$jsonText = file_get_contents('php://input');

Comment: It is to get the input from json. @ShoyebSheikh

Comment: why did you delete the answer? I tried your answer, works well. All records are getting inserted. But when I try to look the output in json format. It give s syntax error. @ShoyebSheikh

Comment: bro you edited code, that's why I deleted my answer.

Comment: Edited the code to show you my efforts. It's not showing any error in xml type it gives messages of success. But in Json output its only showing unexpected 'S'  , syntax error.@ShoyebSheikh

Comment: how to see json syntax error's details in postman? @ShoyebSheikh

Comment: Okay, the response should be out of the for loop, take these statements out of the for loop,  if ($rows < 1) {
                $response = array("status" => -1, "message" => "Failed to send Invitation., unknown reason");
                return $response;
            } else {
                $response = array("status" => 1, "message" => "Invitation sent.", "Invitation:" => $invitation);
                return $response;
            }

Comment: but I want to show response for each invitation. If it exists or not. @ShoyebSheikh

Comment: do var_dump($response): die(); just before  echo(json_encode($response)); in sendInvite.php

Comment: try and put echo(json_encode($response)); in sendInvite() function in Invitation class, like this, if ($rows < 1) { $response = array("status" => -1, "message" => "Failed to send Invitation., unknown reason"); echo(json_encode($response)); } else { $response = array("status" => 1, "message" => "Invitation sent.", "Invitation:" => $invitation); echo(json_encode($response)); }

Comment: Please check edited question.@ShoyebSheikh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <?php

   error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
   ini_set('display_errors', '1');

   require 'Invitation.php';

   $jsonText = file_get_contents('php://input');

   if(empty($jsonText))
   {
      $response = array("status"=>-2,"message"=>"Empty request");
      die(json_encode($response));
   }

$response = array();

   $json = json_decode($jsonText);
  foreach ($json as $jsn) {
   foreach($jsn as $j)
    {
      $date= $j -> date;
      $invitee_no = $j -> invitee_no;
      $status = $j -> status;
      $invitation = new Invitation("",$date,$invitee_no,$status);

       $response[] = $invitation->sendInvite();


    } 
 }
echo(json_encode($response));
 ?>

I have used foreach for array.
```

Comment: I am sending input like this {
"invitations" : [

{

"date" : "12/08/2016",
"invitee_no" : "5365",
"status" : "1"
},
{

"date" : "12/08/2016",
"invitee_no" : "5359",
"status" : "1"
}
] @Shoyeb Sheikh

Comment: @ Sid, I have updated my answer , please check. your json should be like,    {"invitations" : [ { "date" : "12/08/2016", "invitee_no" : "5365", "status" : "1" }, { "date" : "12/08/2016", "invitee_no" : "5359", "status" : "1" } ]}

Comment: can you please look at my edited question? @Shoyeb Sheikh

Comment: I did, use my code it will work, I have tested it. If not var_dump($json); and paste it here.